# cap deploy with ignoring a few files

Tags: git, capistrano

I've a few **unstaged** and **untracked** files in local GIT repo. If I run `cap deploy`, would they be ignored? I hope yes. I simply want those files to be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capistrano use GIT to deploy your files. They can only deploy files that are included in your GIT repository. So its deploing only files that have a commit.

Untracked and modified files cannot be deployed because that are not included and added  in your repo.

Comment: When you say "your GIT repository", do you mean in my local GIT repo or in live GIT repo? Sorry for the ignorance! I assume that it is LIVE one. ??

Comment: Then question is how you use Capistrano. Normally Capistrano connect over SSH to the Server and run a command like git pull. Then you have to push your changes first because the remote and use the remote repo. There are some ways to work with Capistrano. The best way is to read the documentation